# Maven SCM - Git time out

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I just tried to import an existing project into eclipse by using the Git SCM plugin for maven.

If I use Git command line and import the maven project manually everything works fine, but the SCM plugin throws a time out error:

```
Read timed out after 30.000 ms
```

In eclipse preferences, I changed the remote connection time out for Git without any effect. Obviously this only effects EGit. How do I change settings for the maven Git SCM plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy maybe which is configured in the git command line and not in eclipse?

Comment: No, I am not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You could raise a bug against the m2e project at https://bugs.eclipse.org if you think it's a missing feature with the Maven support.

Comment: Is it really missing? I thought it was just me who didn't know where to adjust this setting.